# How to get a specific node value with xpath when id is in element instead of attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

With the xpath `/levels/level[@id="3"]/value` I can get the value of level where id=3 like this:

```
<levels>
     <level id="2">
          <value>25</value>
     </level>
     <level id="3">
          <value>33</value>
     </level>
     <level id="4">
          <value>44</value>
     </level>
</levels>
```

but the XML I am reading is formatted without attributes like this:

```
<levels>
     <level>
          <id>2</id>
          <value>25</value>
     </level>
     <level>
          <id>3</id>
          <value>33</value>
     </level>
     <level>
          <id>4</id>
          <value>44</value>
     </level>
</levels>
```

**What is the equivalent xpath for this second XML block which will get the value of level where id=3?** (It is not guaranteed that id=3 will always be the second node.)

Comment: Your XML is not valid. It contains an extra unclosed <level> element

Comment: thanks, fixed for clarity sakes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following:

```
/levels/level[id/text() = "3"]/value
```

or

```
/levels/level[id/. = "3"]/value
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler/shorter**:

```
/*/*[id = 3]/value
```

Comment: +1 Nice shorter example @Dimitre. I still like to use explicit path syntax, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @Garett, You are welcome. Location steps with full paths are good for education purposes. Using the abbreviated syntax above isn't just "another syntax" -- its evaluation is slightly more efficient (as the element names aren't verified).